# An upper estimation of n tuples

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $w:\mathbb Z\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be a function s.t. $\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z}w(i)=\sigma<\infty$. Let F be a finite subset of $\mathbb Z$.

How to proof that $$\sum_{(i_1,\dots ,i_n)\in F^n}w(0)w(i_1-i_2)w(i_2-i_3)\dots w(i_{n-1}-i_n)\leq|F|\sigma^n?$$

It is obvious when $n=2$, but I don't know how to solve it for general $n$.

Comment: Is $Z$ the integer numbers? Is the sum over $i_1\geq i_2\geq i_3geq \cdots \geq i_n$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Z is the integer numbers. The sum is over all n-tuples in $F^n$, which has the number of $|F|^n$. $|F|$ denotes the cardinality of F.